# CSS: How to control what happens when browser shrinks + Floats

Tags: html, css

I'm testing out some code for a random personal project and I'm looking to place 3 boxes side by side (I believe as divs). But as you'll see they're not really centered (as three)/spaced out so well. I figured assign them unique IDs and increase padding but is there a more efficient way?

[image: Current Setup]

Also when the screen shrinks, the third box dips underneath, while the second box is still on the same line I want it so all boxes drop at the same time. 
[image: Image dipping early]

Unfortunately, I need more reputation to post my code in the proper format it seems.

Comment: Please add some code. AFAIK, you don't need more reputation to post your code. Just use `code markdown`.

Comment: Please include code in the question itself or better still a [MCVE]

Comment: to post code in your question just do ctrl+k and paste in the marked line, you can do it with no rep. Also @Slash_D has provided you with exactly what you need to do in order to keep those boxes from exisiting on another line when your screen shrinks.

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure if I get you correctly.

For "*But as you'll see they're not really centered (as three)/spaced out so well. I figured assign them unique IDs and increase padding but is there a more efficient way?*", if you wanna make them horizontally centered, you can try this:

1. wrap them in a container node.
2. assign a `width` to this container in its style.
3. set both `margin-left` and `margin-right` of this container to `auto`

This should then make these 3 boxes (actually the container) horizontally centered.

For "_Also when the screen shrinks, the third box dips underneath, while the second box is still on the same line I want it so all boxes drop at the same time. _", perhaps `width: calc(100% / 3)` is what you want to put in the styles of these boxes.

Answer (score 0):

In modern web browsers, even if @Slash_D response is correct, you can get a more flexible alignment using flexbox (here you have a complete guide https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

Futhermore, if you want all the containers drop at the same time, you have to deal directly with media query based on resolutions (https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) , or use a grid system, like bootstrap, that helps you with media queries based on classess (https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#how-it-works)

Hope it helps